# investigating oscillation phenomena of a driver circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillation

There is a driver circuit ,At first glance it amplified great the signal however when I probed R1 resistor as shown below on my lab scope with DC input , I saw oscillations.
Now when I did step response of the circuit as shown below I see the oscillations.
I also know from analog design course that i can try and see the AC response.
LT1028 is -1 stable ,how does it influence the connection between the stages so I will not get oscillations. 
What could cause instability in such configuration? 
Thanks.
https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1028fd.pdf

[image]

[image]

[image]